# Combine multiple sheets in one master file

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I am applying the below formula where I want to combine the live data from multiple sheets to one consolidate sheet in horizontal format & here my header is same... but I am getting an error as:

> **Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: col1**

```
=QUERY({'MATHEWS K J'!A2:AR;'VASU P'!A2:AR;'ARVIND RAJ J'!A2:AR;'THIVYA D'!A2:AR;'PRASANTH V'!A2:AR;'SATHIK BASHA S'!A2:AR;'GAYATHRI V'!A2:AR;'INDIRA R'!A2:AR},"select * where col1 is not null", 0)
```

the first column is having a date as like **4/2/2019 10:37:10** (Timestamp) in this format & the sheet is linked with Google Forms where the user can fill the form & getting output on Google sheet.. (in one sheet having 44 columns)

required help for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- instead of **`col1`** use **`Col1`**

```
=QUERY({'MATHEWS K J'!A2:AR;
             'VASU P'!A2:AR;
       'ARVIND RAJ J'!A2:AR;
           'THIVYA D'!A2:AR;
         'PRASANTH V'!A2:AR;
     'SATHIK BASHA S'!A2:AR;
         'GAYATHRI V'!A2:AR;
           'INDIRA R'!A2:AR}, "select * where Col1 is not null", 0)
```